# select from A if id = 1 and select from B if id = 2 from?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table(for example C) that contanin common field from A,B like this:

C fields:
id, title , description,

and each (A,B)tables have private fields like this:
A fields:
picture,year,
B fields:
writer,college

i want select all data on the A,B tables that records only contain own fields like this:

first record: id, title , description,picture,year 
 and 
second record: id, title , description,writer,college

Comment: What have you tried already? I think you're looking for a join SQL statement, do a quick Google search on JOINs.

Comment: no, is not with join. i want thing like this: select * from C and if id = 1 select * from A and if id = 2 select from B. i don't think this query is possible with join.

Comment: Unless you have something to link the tables together, it's impossible to select based on what you already have, for example the columns from C do not match any columns from A or B. However, if A and B had a new column called "id" as C does, you could link them with join. This seems highly impractical... what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Daniel "i have a table(for example C) that contanin common field from A,B"  that means a and b have the id field

Comment: Okay, got you. Let me show you how you can use join to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Hey man I think you should read more about the sql join which you can read [more here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

I think you need something like this :

```
        SELECT
       c.id,
       c.title,
       c.description,
       a.picture,
       a.year 
    from
       c 
    INNER JOIN
       a 
          on c.id=a.id ;
SELECT
   c.id,
   c.title,
   c.description,
   b.writer,
   b.college 
from
   c 
INNER JOIN
   b 
      on c.id=b.id
```

You will get :

id, title , description,  picture, year

id, title , description,writer,college

to join all 3 tables together you could do like:

```
select fields_list
from
     a
        inner join
     b
        on a.common_field = b.common_field
        inner join 
     c
        on b.common_field = c.common_field
```

Good luck. Hope this will give you a little clue of what you want.

Comment: Beat me to it, nice one.

Comment: Thanks bru @Daniel

Comment: it's not work. see i have six table that contain fields of six products. i want select common fields from products from C and select  private fields from each table depend on sub_id column from C.

Comment: can you post your real field tables man and also the ones that you wanna select, so I can be able assist you further,